# How to apply window similar to rows between current row and unbounded preceding in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have below sample dataframe as :- i.e. id, name across different year and quater with different value

```
id name year quater value 
1  bn   2017 2
1  bn   2017 3     4.5
1  bn   2017 4
1  bn   2018 1
1  bn   2018 2
1  bn   2018 3
2  an   2017 2     2.3   
2  an   2017 3     3.3
2  an   2017 4     4.5
2  an   2018 1   
2  an   2018 2
2  an   2018 3
```

For a given id and name:-

1. if current value is null and no previous value or all the previous value is null then status is 2
2. if current value is null and any of the value above that quater and
   year is not null then status is 0
3. if current value is not null and all the values above that quater
   and year is null or previous is not there then status is 1
4. if current value is not null and any of the value above that quater and
   year is not null then status is 0

   1 - new
   0 - not new
   2 - not sure

Result should be :-

```
id name year quater value status
1  bn   2017 2            2
1  bn   2017 3     4.5    1
1  bn   2017 4            0
1  bn   2018 1            0
1  bn   2018 2            0
1  bn   2018 3            0
2  an   2017 2     2.3    1 
2  an   2017 3     3.3    0
2  an   2017 4     4.5    0
2  an   2018 1            0
2  an   2018 2            0
2  an   2018 3            0
```

This will help to identify if the id and name is new(1)/existing(0)/notsure(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df.loc[:, 'cum_value'] = df.groupby(['id', 'name']).value.cumsum()

def get_status(value, cum_value):
    if value!=0 and value == cum_value:
        return 1
    elif value==0 and cum_value==0:
        return 2
    else:
        return 0

df.loc[:, 'status'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_status(row['value'], row['cum_value'] ), axis=1)
```

I changed the `NaN` values to 0 to make things easier. If you'd like to change them back to `NaN`, you can do so easily, e.g. :

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[df['value'] == 0, 'value'] = np.NaN
```